# SQL salvar e retornar imagem base64

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, base64, advpl

Estou salvando uma imagem no SQL Server usando o campo do tipo varbinary(max).

Porém, quando executo a consulta para retornar ao front, só consigo retornar convertendo o campo para varchar.

Minha dúvida é como fazer a leitura da string retornada, e se essa é a melhor forma de se fazer isso.

A string salva no meu banco como varbinary é "0x646174613A696D6167652F6A7065673B6261736536342C2F396A2F346749" e o que retorna para o front quando converto em varchar é "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gI", por exemplo.

Obrigado desde já!

Notei que o problema em si é quando tento retornar o valor usando ADVPL, eu incluo o campo no select, mas quando tento retornar ele usando: variavel := qry->campobase64, ele diz que não consegue localizar o alias "campobase64", e se eu removo essa linha o código executa normalmente.

Comment: Alterei a forma de como salvo para varchar(max), agora a string da imagem é armazenada a seguinte forma: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJ...", quando tento retornar dando um select na coluna para o front retorna uma mensagem "invalid field name...", se eu removo o valor do select e retorno em branco vai sem problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O DBAccess - Gateway de acesso a dados relacionais -- usado pelo Protheus para ler e gravar dados nos Bancos de Dados homologados -- até pouco tempo atrás náo permitia a leitura de campos LOB ou similares diretamente por Query. Um campo do tipo `varchar(max)` no MSSQL é usado no AdvPL para emular um campo do tipo `"M" Memo` do AdvPL, que permite a gravação de conteúdo binário, como é o caso da imagem.

Se eu não me engano, na nova Build do Protheus 12, batizada de "Lobo Guará", usando o EMBEDDED SQL -- recurso de escrever uma Query diretamente dentro de um fonte AdvPL -- já é possível ler diretamente um campo desse tipo por Query.

Para builds anteriores, a única solução é recuperar uma chave de busca do registro na Query -- como por exemplo o campo `R_E_C_N_O_` da tabela -- e posicionar no registro correspondente usando o ALIAS da tabela aberta em modo de compatibilidade ISAM -- modo tradicional de aberturas de tabela do ERP Microsiga -- e ler o campo "M" Memo usando a sintaxe `ALIAS->CAMPO`.

Embora seja possível fazer uma Query com `CAST()`, para contornar as proteções do DBAccess e retornar uma string de tamanho fixo, normalmente você têm juma limitação de tamanho - por exemplo não será possível no MSSQL trazer mais do que 8 KB de dados deste campo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Era exatamente disso que precisava.